# Libreoffice - update links automatically upon opening?

Tags: python, libreoffice, dde

I have an .ods file that contains many links that must be updated automatically. As I understand there is no easy way to do this with macros or libreoffice command arguments, so I am trying to make all links update upon opening the file and then will save the file and exit.

All links are DDE links which should be able to update automatically (and are set to do so in Edit > Links), and I have also enabled this in Tools > Options > Calc > General > Always Update Links When Opening, as well as Tools > Options > Calc > Formulas > Always Recalculate. **However, I am still being prompted with a popup to manually update links upon opening, and links will not be up to date if I do not select Update.** I need these DDE links to update automatically, why isn't this working?

If there is no solution there, I am also willing to try to update links via Python. Will Uno work with libreoffice to do this without ruining any preexisting graphs in the file like openpyxl does?

Comment: What is the cell formula -- Does it look like `=DDE("soffice","c:\users\username\desktop\1.ods","Sheet1.A1")` or `='file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/1.ods'#$Sheet1.A2` or `{='file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/1.ods'#$Sheet1.A3}`?  DDE can mean several different things.

Comment: The first: "=DDE("soffice","file:///Users/crushendo/Desktop/Folder/Report-Data.xlsx","Weekly Report.A1")"

Comment: I have code to update the DDE links, but the API does not provide a method to suppress the prompt upon opening the file (i've tried to run the code on  "document open" event). 
So, I guess you're out of luck: you have to answer "Yes" if you want the actual values.

Comment: I agree.  @ngulam, do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The API does not provide a method to suppress the prompt upon opening the file!

I've tried running StarBasic code to update DDE links on "document open" event, but the question keeps popping up.

So, I guess you're out of luck: you have to answer "Yes" if you want the actual values.

[posted the comment to OP's question here again as answer, as suggested by @Jim K]

Comment: Well that's terrible. Is there any workaround in headless mode that you've found, or any other way to update the links without any human input? I need to update links on an automatic timer program. I have been looking into pyoo as a solution, but the library is having some trouble with the Uno library dependency for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, to update DDE links of a CALC document (in headless mode)

```
Sub  autoupdate_DDE
' 20170314
' load library with help function
GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary( "Tools" )
' get all DDE links of document '
dde_links = ThisComponent.DDELinks
' get array of names '
aEN = dde_links.getElementNames()
' work on every DDE link '
for i = 0 to UBound( aEN() )
   xTF = dde_links.getByName( aEN( i ) )
   xTF.refresh()
Next
End Sub
```

note: this snippet is for CALC only, WRITER uses `textfield`s for DDE links.

[provided as another answer, in order to use code formatting. Added single  quotation strings at end of comments, to retain code colorization]